# Will using Windows 7 drivers for Windows Server 2008 R2 result in bad software installs?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers

I have been tasked with installing some server software on a box that is using:

Asus Rampage Extreme 2 Motherboard
Windows Server 2008 R2
Drivers for Windows 7 (because as far as I know, Asus does not distribute specific drivers for Windows Server 2008)

I'm running into strange behaviour trying to install software that should not be rocket science.  This includes SQL Server 2008 R2, SharePoint, Team Foundation Server, IIS, etc.

For example, IIS is throwing errors when trying to install Microsoft CRM, so it was uninstalled.  Now it won't install at all.  SQL Server installs and throws an error that says "External component has thrown an exception".  The service starts, but when you try to connect to it a message that says the server is in single-user mode appears.  Tried to restart the service and it won't start after being stopped.  The log after restarting says it's trying to read the master database files from a drive letter that doesn't even exist.  Scared it's not worth working through these errors as they seem absurd.

Any thoughts?  Would it be best to instead run Windows 7 with Server 2008 running on a virtual server?

I'm curious to know if anyone else has experienced similar-type errors with software installation problems using Win 7 drivers on Server 2008.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Maybe run your servers on server-class hardware?  That looks sure looks like a consumer kit to me.  What evidence do you have that this is actually a driver problem?  You mention drivers, but then you start talking about software problems which really shouldn't have anything to do with drivers.

Answer (score 3):

@Greg, I hate to say it and I'm not trying to slam you, but trying to run W2K8 on a piece of hardware that isn't built nor certified for W2K8 is only going to leave you frustrated and puzzled. It's analogous to trying to force motorcycle tires on a car. Yes, they're similar and yes, you could probably make them work by using a hammer and crowbar, but it isn't right and it's never going to be right. If you need to install and run applications that require a server OS than purchase the appropriate hardware and save yourself a lot of grief.

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that install Windows 7 drivers on a Windows 2008 R2 wont give you any issue.

As example if you buy a a Windows 7 laptop and you install Windows Server 2008 R2 on it most of your devices will work ok. Maybe wont your bluethoot device.

That is due Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 share the same kernel code, the access to the devices is the same. The same thing happens with Windows Vista and Windows 2008 but not whit Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP.

The bast majority of drivers will install out of the box, sometimes dont because the INF file of the driver dont allow it. With this trick of a Technet Blog you can install them: Installing [Windows Server 2008 R2 on a notebook and getting all those required drivers](http://blogs.technet.com/b/roblarson/archive/2009/05/02/installing-windows-server-2008-r2-on-a-notebook-and-getting-all-those-required-drivers.aspx).

So, tipically you dont have any problem but always keep in mind that it is not suppoted by Micosoft.